# Using String Type in Integer Type?

Tags: c#, string, int

i have a serious problem in C# console application,  the following code doesn't work as what i want... it must ask me to type the following letters value, then it must calculate with the values i typed, but when i type a character such as '**x**', it doesn't make it equivalent to "**1**", how can i solve that problem???, what is the certain solution??
**"x" value should be equivalent to 1**

```
string nun = "2";
        Console.WriteLine("Type the 'A' value");
        double a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (a=='x') {

            a = 1

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Type the 'B' value");
        double b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Type the 'C' value");
        double c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        double delta = Math.Pow(b,2) - (4*a*c);


        if(delta > 0 ) {

            double x1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(delta) / 2 * a);
            Console.WriteLine("value of x1: {0}",Convert.ToInt32(x1));
            double x2 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(delta) / 2 * a);


            Console.WriteLine("value of x2: {0}",Convert.ToInt32(x2));
        }

        else if (delta < 0) {

            Console.WriteLine("there is no any different real root in this equation!");

        }
```

Comment: How would you compare a double to a char?

Comment: Why not type `1` instead of `x`? Your code shows that you want to allow user to enter `number` not any non-numeric string.

Comment: i am trouble in type conversions :)

Comment: How can you expect a double be equal to `x` . `double a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (a=='x') `

Comment: king king that's actual problem for me, how can i solve it ??

Comment: a user should be able to type integer and string values as well

Comment: When you cast char to numeric type you get its ASCII code.

Comment: Instead of `Math.Pow(b,2)` it is easier to write `b*b`. And you need parentheses in the formulae for `x1` and `x2`, as in `double x1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Type the 'A' value");
    string s = Console.ReadLine();        
    double a = s == "x" ? 1 : Convert.ToInt32(s);
```

**NOTE**: the code doesn't care about some conversion exception, you should use `try-catch` to deal with it.

Comment: I think, with the info we have, this the best solution. But i really can't understand what OP want to attain.

Comment: problem solved, thats really easy, but it didnt come to my mind ;) thanks a lot

Comment: `try`–`catch` is not optimal. You could use `int.TryParse`. For example: `int a; if (s == "x") { a = 1; } else if (!int.TryParse(s, out a)) { /* handle wrong input */ }`

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen it's even better to **prevent user from typing any non-numeric character**, don't need to use any `try-catch`, or `TryParse`.